# android how to set a button on image

Tags: android, button, scroll, zooming

I want to set a button on image([TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)). I want this button to be fixed on image(map). So I can scroll/zoom and this button should be fixed on its' place. I truied to use an AbsoluteLayout(it's deprecated) and RelativeLayout. None of it hepled.

```
    //
    // DecimalFormat rounds to 2 decimal places.
    //
    df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    scrollPositionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_position);
    zoomedRectTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zoomed_rect);
    currentZoomTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_zoom);
    image = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    //
    // Set the OnTouchImageViewListener which updates edit texts
    // with zoom and scroll diagnostics.
    //
    image.setOnTouchImageViewListener(new OnTouchImageViewListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMove() {
            PointF point = image.getScrollPosition();
            RectF rect = image.getZoomedRect();
            float currentZoom = image.getCurrentZoom();
            boolean isZoomed = image.isZoomed();
            scrollPositionTextView.setText("x: " + df.format(point.x) + " y: " + df.format(point.y));
            zoomedRectTextView.setText("left: " + df.format(rect.left) + " top: " + df.format(rect.top)
                    + "\nright: " + df.format(rect.right) + " bottom: " + df.format(rect.bottom));
            currentZoomTextView.setText("getCurrentZoom(): " + currentZoom + " isZoomed(): " + isZoomed);
        }
    });
```

Can you give me an advice? Or at least a reference to read. I want to make something similar like in fallout shelter or clash of clans(where you can scroll and see your base).

Comment: I have similar query,have u found solution to this? Then please share !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Framelayout to display button on top of image and view.offsetLeftAndRight method to change button position.

e.g.

```
int lastX;
int lastY;
void setButtonPosition(int x, int y) {
    button.offsetLeftAndRight(x - lastX);
    button.offsetTopAndBottom(y - lastY);
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Button" />
</FrameLayout>
```